# Is using tableView:willSelectedRowAtIndexPath: correct way to pass variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

Hello i am trying to pass variable with segue.

I am getting variable to pass with tableView:willSelectedRowAtIndexPath: is this correct way? If it is not, how should i achieve this? (Note: It is working like this.)

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedCoffeeShop = [coffeeShops objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return indexPath;
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"coffeeShopDetailSegue"]) {
        CoffeeShopDetailViewController *controller = (CoffeeShopDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [segue destinationViewController];
        controller.coffeeShop = selectedCoffeeShop;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, just remove the `[segue destinationViewController]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your segue is made from the cell itself, then there is no need to implement either willSelectRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You only need prepareForSegue:sender: since the sender argument will be the cell, and you can use that to get the indexPath you need,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"coffeeShopDetailSegue"]) {
        NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        CoffeeShopDetailViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.coffeeShop = coffeeShops[row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That way to do it is absolutely fine.

Another way would be to remove the automatic segue trigger from storyboards and instead implement:
`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

It could look like this:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   selectedCoffeeShop = [coffeeShops objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"coffeeShopDetailSegue" sender:self];
   return indexPath;
 }
```

In that case you still need your implementation of `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

You could also do it completely without segues, using `UINavigationController`, but then you'd have to instantiate the `CoffeeShopDetailViewController` programmatically as well.

Your approach is perfectly fine though!

As noted in the comments, you can remove `[segue destinationViewController];`, since this returns the destination view controller which you already saved in the variable `controller` in the line right above. :)